# How to show a calculated value between two dates with just the hour and the minute above 24 hours of difference in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I Have an property called Duration, this property is a calculation of two other properties called StartDate and EndDate.

The problem is, I need the difference between those two dates in the format "hh:mm", and I could do that with a lot of codes and solutions I found on the Internet, but I always have the same problem at the end, the day count...

Today I have the following code:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Duration
{
 get
 {
  if (StartDate != null && EndDate != null)
  {
   return (EndDate - StartDate).Value.ToString().Substring(0, 5);
  }
  return null;
 }
 set
 {
  if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
 }
}
```

Considering we have the following values of Start and End Dates:
StartDate = 2019/03/14 - 10:43 AM
EndDate = 2019/03/14 - 11:00 AM

And it show an output like this:

Duration = 00:16

But when I have more than 24 hours of difference, it counts the day and I get an invalid value.

For Example: 
StartDate = 2019/03/05 - 03:00 AM
EndDate = 2019/03/15 - 04:00 AM

It prints:

**Duration = 1.01:**

It's couting the day, and I need it to be in **hours:minutes** format.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: DateTime has a [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) format. And [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) has TotalDays
 etc

Comment: Please clarify the second example.  Do you want the output to be `10.01` or `10:01:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(1).AddHours(2).AddMinutes(3);

TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate;

int totalHours = (int)difference.TotalMinutes / 60;
int totalMinutes = (int)difference.TotalMinutes % 60;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", totalHours.ToString("D2"), totalMinutes.ToString("D2")));
```

Output:

> 26:03

Which stands for 26 hours and 3 minutes passed, as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

Best not to use SubString.

If you subtract a date from another date, you get a `TimeSpan`

You can do `ToString()` on this or use its properties to display what you want, however since you want to display total hours rather than just the hours component, you'll have to use the individual properties:

```
 var startDate = DateTime.Now;
 var endDate = startDate.AddHours(30).AddMinutes(20);

 var difference = endDate - startDate;

 var hoursComponent = ((int)difference.TotalHours).ToString("D2");
 var minutesComponent = difference.Minutes.ToString("D2");

 Console.WriteLine($"{hoursComponent}:{minutesComponent}");
```

Something like this should do it. I've put the D2 in to force it to display a leading zero if it's only a single digit. I cast `TotalHours` to an `int` because TotalHours actually returns a double with a fraction component which you don't want. I didn't use `TotalMinutes` because I don't think the Second component is relevant.

Comment: I tried it, but TotalHours gives me some results like "5,1.1:"

Comment: Note that I cast it to an integer with `(int)`, forcing it to be a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
hours = (datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours().ToString();
```

Comment: It tried it before I ask the question, but unfortunately I does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the timespan:

```
TimeSpan span = (EndDate - StartDate);

String.Format("{0}:{1}",span.Hours, span.Minutes);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2, Look at the code exemple with a total hours of 5k+ the result of Hours is only 5! Wrong property

Comment: I tried this way too, but it does not shows the way I want

Comment: It was wrong way around. I edited the answer, should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ToString` method of the `TimeSpan` to format your output as you wish:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime? startDate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 5, 3, 0, 0);
    DateTime? endDate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 15, 4, 0, 0);

    TimeSpan result = (endDate - startDate).Value;
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss"));
}
```

Output:

> 10:01:00:00